# Is it good practice to send in multiple mail methods in an ActionMailer Model action, or should that logic be kept outside of the Mailer action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style, actionmailer

Which would be the preferred?

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base

  # this?
  def bid_end_notify_failed_bidders(job)
    @job = job
    bidders = @job.bidders
    bidders.delete(@job.winner)
    bidders.each do |t|
      mail(:to => t.email, ....)
    end
  end

  # or this?
  def notify_failed_bid(bidder)
    mail(:to => bidder ...)
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest method #2, this is because you want to be agile in the way you send the email.

The most regular way of using it is:

- declare an instance
- declare any relations you need from the instance
- pass the instances to the Mailer::Base method
- Deliver

Example:

user = User.first

bets_won = user.bets_won

Mailer.send_congrats(users, bets_won).deliver!

Now it will only use the data it's being served so no logic has to be done by the Mailer class
also this approach will allow you to reuse the method easily.